# How to display a limited number of records that must have a minimal field in stream api?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a stream and I want to display the five records with the lowest rate. I understand that I need to first use sorting, and then use the limit() method to display as many elements as I need. However, I don't understand how to implement this.

```
   Stream <Collection <Logs>> stre = Stream.of(firstCollection, lastCollection);
        stre.flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Logs::getId,
                Collectors.mapping(Logs::getTime,
    Collectors.toList())))
   .forEach ((id, list) -> {});
```

I need this output:

For example, I want to choose people

```
Jasmine, seller, 31          
Andry, blogger, 12
Samanta, model, 16 
Mike, programmer, 20
Debby, seller, 19
Mark, artist, 12
...

more than 100 records
```

I want to select people from 15-18 years old and I want the maximum number of people in the sample to be 3

```
Mark, artist, 12
Andry, blogger, 12
Samanta, model, 16
```

How to implement this logic using stream API?

Comment: What is the first block of code for?

Comment: You need to clarify what you want to do.  Either sort or filter.  And  you talk about age and rate but show only one numeric value.  You also talk about the first five but only show three in the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a stream and I want to display the five records with the lowest rate. I understand that i need to first use sorting, and then use the limit.

I can help you with above requirement as stated.  But the filtering of ages between 15 an 18 doesn't make sense for the shown output.

- it isn't clear if your records are an age or a time.
- you specified five records above but your output shows only three

I would advise not using `limit`.  You've already sorted the list so why not keep it and print a `subList`.  I created two `Lists` to start to reproduce what you had in your question.  Note that I am using a `record` (introduced in Java 15) instead of a `class` since it is easier to code but your class should work just fine as a drop in replacement.  Note that I may have renamed the class and getters incorrectly.

```
record Logs(String getName, String getJob, int getTime) {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getName + ", " + getJob + ", " + getTime;
    }
}
```

Now create the two lists.

```
List<Logs> firstCollection =
        List.of(new Logs("Jasmine", "seller", 31),
                new Logs("Andry", "blogger", 12),
                new Logs("Samanta", "model", 16));
List<Logs> lastCollection =
        List.of(new Logs("Mike", " programmer", 20),
                new Logs("Debby", "seller", 19),
                new Logs("Mark", "artist", 12));
```

And compute the sorted list.

```
List<Logs> result = Stream.of(firstCollection, lastCollection)
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Logs::getTime))
        .toList(); // java 16 or .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Now just print a `subList` using standard indexing ranges of the sorted list.

```
result.subList(0,3).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Prints (as shown in your question)

```
Andry, blogger, 12
Mark, artist, 12
Samanta, model, 16
```

But if you really don't need the sorted values, then...

```
List<Logs> result = Stream.of(firstCollection, lastCollection)
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Logs::getTime))
        .limit(3)
        .toList(); // java 16 or .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And just print the list normally.

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about people example, I would use a predicate for getting a sublist with people within required age range, apply sorting and then apply a limit:

```
entries.stream()
    .filter(x -> x.getAge() >= 15 && x.getAge() <= 18)
    .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Entry::getAge))
    .limit(3)
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
```